# Add Group By in query and a counting variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query here :

```
SELECT nsd.REGISTRATION_DATE,nsd.Subject_Name,nsd.Subject_Code,nsda.District_Name, nsda.Region_Name
    FROM tbl1 AS nsd 
    LEFT JOIN
    tbl2 AS nsda ON nsd.Subject_Code = nsda.Subject_Code
```

I need to group this query by `Subject_Name, District_Name and Region_Name.` i also want to add a counter which tells me for example:

```
Subject|Nr.Total| Region| District
Maths   2        Austria Tyrol
Maths   5        Austria Vienna
```

When i try to add the group by i get an error, it says something about aggregate function:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'tbl1.REGISTRATION_DATE' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the error please, and add some sample data.

Comment: post your attempts and people can show you where you made a mistake rather than asking them to provide a solution for you.

Comment: Which column are you trying to group by???

Comment: In SELECT list, you can only have those columns which are in Group By clause or in aggregate functions. If you want to include additional columns, use analytical functions

Comment: My attempt, is GROUP BY nsd.Subject_Name, nsd.District_Name, nsd.Region_Name and i get the error i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using `REGISTRATION_DATE` in your `SELECT`, you can omit it.

```
SELECT
    nsd.Subject_Name,
    [Nr. Total] = ISNULL(COUNT(nsda.Subject_Code), 0),
    nsda.Region_Name,
    nsda.District_Name
FROM tbl1 nsd
LEFT JOIN tbl2 nsda
    ON nsd.Subject_Code = nsda.Subject_Code
GROUP BY nsd.Subject_Name, nsda.Region_Name, nsda.District_Name
```

In SQL Server, columns in the `SELECT` must appear in the [**`GROUP BY`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm accepting it in a few minutes :)
worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT nsd.Subject_Name AS [Subject], count(*) AS [Nr.Total], nsda.Region_Name AS [Region], nsda.District_Name AS [District]
    FROM tbl1 AS nsd 
    LEFT JOIN
    tbl2 AS nsda ON nsd.Subject_Code = nsda.Subject_Code
Group by nsd.Subject_Name, nsda.Region_Name, nsda.District_Name
```

If you need 'tbl1.REGISTRATION_DATE' in select, add this too in Group By statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:-

```
SELECT nsd.REGISTRATION_DATE, nsd.Subject_Name, nsd.Subject_Code, nsda.District_Name, nsda.Region_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl1 AS nsd 
LEFT JOIN
tbl2 AS nsda ON nsd.Subject_Code = nsda.Subject_Code
GROUP BY nsd.REGISTRATION_DATE, nsd.Subject_Name, nsd.Subject_Code, nsda.District_Name, nsda.Region_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT nsd.Subject_Name as Subject, count(*) as 'Nr.Total', nsd.Region_Name as Region, nsd.District_Name as District
FROM tbl1 AS nsd 
LEFT JOIN
tbl2 AS nsda ON nsd.Subject_Code = nsda.Subject_Code
GROUP BY nsd.Subject_Name, nsd.District_Name, nsd.Region_Name
```